# WPF: How do I handle events in a DataTemplate that is in a separate file?

Tags: wpf, events, datatemplate

I have a DataTemplate with a ListView control. This DataTemplate is located in Templates.xaml (which is a ResourceDictionary). Template.xaml is then included into my main UserControl SourceManager.xaml through ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries. I want to raise the SelectionChanged event of the DataTemplate's ListView but I want the handler in the code behind to be in SourceManager.xaml.cs.

How can I achieve that?

Templates.xaml:

```
<ResourceDictionary x:Class="LawBib.Templates"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">

<DataTemplate x:Key="SectionTemplate">
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Title}" />
        <ListView x:Name="GroupList" ItemsSource="{Binding XPath=Source}">
            <ListView.Template>
                <ControlTemplate>
                    <WrapPanel IsItemsHost="True">

                    </WrapPanel>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </ListView.Template>
            <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel>
                        <Image Source="images/source.png" />
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding XPath=@Title}" HorizontalAlignment="Center" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListView.ItemTemplate>
        </ListView>
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

SourceManager.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="LawBib.SourceManager"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300" Background="#f5f7f8">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Templates.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </UserControl.Resources>
...
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `SelectionChanged` is a `RoutedEvent`, you can apply it to your `UserControl` like so:

```
<UserControl ...
             ListView.SelectionChanged="MyEventHandler" />
```

Be aware that this event handler will be called for **all** `Selector` derived classes (as `Selector` is where the event is defined and raised) that are descendants of your `UserControl`, which includes `ComboBox`, `Menu`, `ListBox`, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response, but this solution seems a bit messy as all the selector derived classes will be hitting this handler. Is there another way?

Comment: You could add a code-behind to your ResourceDictionary and add event handlers like you would in the UserControl.  If you do this, the event handlers will be called in the ResourceDictionary's code-behind, and not in your UserControl's.

Comment: Yeah but I need the handlers to be in the UserControl's code behind... That's the whole reason for this question.

Comment: Is there maybe an easy way to access the UserControl class instance from the ResourceDirectory's code behind?

Comment: I can't think of a way of getting at it at all.  In the RoutedEventArgs in the event handler, you should be able to check the Source property to get to the actual control that raised the event.  From there you can determine if it is a control you are interested in.

Answer (score -2):

Create a Behavior

drop it in the Data Template.

that's it.

Comment: I don't think a Behavior is what I need in this case.